# How to change Date format like "yyyy-mm-dd" on the struct without parsing on the table rows?

Tags: datetime, go, time, struct

I would to change EntryDate format like yyyy-mm-dd formated on the struct,

```
type Value struct {
    Id uint `json:”id”`
    EntryDate time.time `json:”entry_date”`
    ProductId int `json:"product_id"`
    Value float64 `json:”value”`
}
```

By default the result like this

```
{
  Id: 11,
  EntryDate: "2017-11-23T00:00:00Z",
  product_id: 1,
  Value: 932.3
},
```

How to change EntryDate format like "yyyy-mm-dd" on the struct without parsing on the code ?

Comment: What "table rows"? Can you post the actual code and problem? Both the Go code and JSON given are invalid.

Comment: This seems like a standard "define your own marshaller" as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142980/json-marshal-one-property-of-struct-array or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596376/go-json-marshaling-an-error (I stopped searching after two, we have quite a few of those questions).

Comment: I mean fetching the result from the table and formatting EntryDate via loops, next render as json. is it possible to change EntryDate type like "yyyy-mm-dd" on the struct?

Comment: So you want to format `time.Time`.  It has a `Format` method: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format

Comment: it work by parsing on the code not on the struct type. how to custom like a time.TIme with other format? is this case impossible?

Comment: What do you mean by parsing on the struct type? You can of course write a new type to store time.

Comment: ok thank you, any reference similar for this?

Comment: If you take them from database you may set another formatting in database and work with like strings

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding you correctly you can do this like this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Value struct {
    Id        uint      `json:”id”`
    EntryDate time.Time `json:”entry_date”`
    ProductId int       `json:"product_id"`
    Value     float64   `json:”value”`
}

func main() {
    val := Value{}
    val.Id = 1
    val.EntryDate = time.Now().UTC()
    val.ProductId = 2
    val.Value = 1.223
    t := val.EntryDate.UTC().Format("2006-01-02")
    fmt.Println("formated time : ", t)
    b, err := json.Marshal(val)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("failed to marshal object", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("actual object", string(b))
}
```

Output

```
 formated time : 2009-11-10
actual object {"Id":1,"EntryDate":"2009-11-10T23:00:00Z","product_id":2,"Value":1.223}
```

Check in Go playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Fc35ealF5BI

Comment: Thank you it's true, but I want to formatting by pre-defining with custom type on the struct like "EntryDate time.CustomFormat". do you know what should I do for making this? please I need reference. thank you